# Dynamic table, insert items in cells, sorted corresponding to thead

Tags: jquery

I have a Table, content is dynamic, so is even the thead content.

I have a list/array of objects called ingredients[].

Items/objects have property called category.

I like to insert this array of objects into the table with the property categories corresponding to the thead columns value. Something like this:

[image]

Her is my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlomak/gFzCk/3237/)**

I want to loop thead to see what th value is there (A,B,C,D). Then loop array of objects and match their categ property with th values, then insert each to corresponding column.

After many hours, many attemps and exploding head, I still can't manage to accomplish this. Please help.

```
    var categ;
    var name;
    var th;
    var tr=$('<tr>');
    for ( var i in ingredients) {
        tr.appendTo($('#tblGrid'));
        for ( var j in thead) {
            $('<td colspan="2" data-id="" data-catg="'+ingredients[i].categ+'">'+ingredients[i].name+'<span  class="pull-right">kr. '+ingredients[i].price+'</span></td>').appendTo(tr);
                th = thead[j];
                categ= ingredients[i].categ;
                name= ingredients[i].name;                  
                    if (categ==th) {
                        //I am lost 
                    }
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: The power of `for` loops and the `.each()` / `.push()` method will helps you achieve this with ease, especially since you are using jQuery.  For starters, I would convert that list of items that you have into a `html` table that you can apply classes to, so you can create specific jQuery selectors for them.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Well, as you see I am already using those functions. I just can't construct it in the right way.

Comment: Hi Khky, I have a slightly working prototype in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ae0oygtu/5/  May I ask for your help in clarifying exactly how the cells should be rendered?  Is it all "a" category for example, supposed to show under the "a" column, etc?

Comment: Alexander Dixon  - Yes it's correct perceived. All the categories need to be fitted under column categories. 
I just noticed that `thead` should also be `colspan='2'` like this: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mazlomak/ae0oygtu/6/)

Fx.: Pppp need to be placed under column B, and Kkkk under column C...and so on.

Comment: @ Khkhy [ALMOST](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ae0oygtu/11/) I am nearly done with this request.  The last step is to remove the empty cells and shift the non-empty cells up to the first rows so that the information flows naturally in the correct column order.

Comment: Oh, I thought I was forgotten. I truly appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Dear Alexander, is there any progress? I tried to remove the empty cells myself, but without any luck.

Comment: @ Khkhy, I have not forgotten about you.  It turns out that the last part is seemingly the hardest.  I have created my own question on [manipulate TDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104875/jquery-inject-td-into-appropriate-column) to get this last part solved.  Please stay tuned and thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery was the best method to achieve this because its psuedo selectors work across all browsers, and let you really pin-point your DOM elements, especially when dealing with tables that have dynamic rows and columns.  The first task was to build up a table overcompensated for all of the TDs (where we can remove empty rows after all the sorting).  Your approach at creating an array of ingredients was fine, but we needed a way to pass in all attributes where needed that was HTML compliant so we could safely iterate.

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ae0oygtu/21/)

```
var ingredients = [];

function addIngredToList(id, name, price, categ) {
  var item = [];
  item.push(id);
  item.push(name);
  item.push(price);
  item.push(categ);
  ingredients.push(item);
}
```

Then we dynamically build up the TDs now that we have all the information for them in an array that we can iterate over.  We put them into the table as soon as it is created in a new row (creating blank TDs where necessary to keep the table flow in order).

```
for (i = 0, z = ingredients.length; i < z; i++) {
  var emptyRow = "<tr class='emptyRow'></tr>";
  $('table#tblGrid').append(emptyRow);
  emptyRowSelector = $('tr.emptyRow');
  for (c = 0, b = ingredients[i].length; c < b; c++) {
    var columnID = " " + $('table#tblGrid').find('th').eq(c).text().toLowerCase().toString();
    var emptyTD = "<td colspan='2' class='emptyTD" + columnID + "'></td>";
    emptyRowSelector.eq(i).append(emptyTD);
  }
}

//Create a TD  with ingredient array attributes.
var $rowScanner = $('table#tblGrid').find('tr').not($('tr:eq(0)'));
var $headerScanner = $('table#tblGrid').find('tr:eq(0) th');

for (g = 0, e = $rowScanner.length; g < e; g++) {
  var idCol = ingredients[g][0];
  var nameCol = ingredients[g][1];
  var priceCol = ingredients[g][2];
  var categCol = ingredients[g][3];

  var tdCell = "<td colspan='2' data-id='" + idCol + "' data-catg='" + categCol + "' class='" + categCol.toLowerCase().toString() + "'>" + nameCol + "<span class='pull-right'>kr." + priceCol + "</span></td>";
  var classChecker = "td." + ingredients[g][3].toString() + "";
  $rowScanner.eq(g).find(classChecker).replaceWith(tdCell).addClass("targetFound");
}

$headerScanner.each(function(i, v) {
  var assignClass = $(this).text();
  $(this).addClass(assignClass).attr("colspan", "2");
});
```

Lastly, with the help of [Jean-Claude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120353/transpose-array-of-tds-into-columns-jquery/37121225#37121225), I was able to create a temporary table that held all the TDs with their attributes and sort them back into the master table grid in ascending order.  Then, after all processes were done, I created an interval that scanned the page for empty table rows, and remove them.

This code was setup with automation in mind, so it is pretty versatile, where the only items that need to be tweaked on a case by case basis are the variables and attributes for the table cells.

```js
var ingredients = [];

function addIngredToList(id, name, price, categ) {
  var item = [];
  item.push(id);
  item.push(name);
  item.push(price);
  item.push(categ);
  ingredients.push(item);
}

addIngredToList(1, "Ooo", 8, "a");
addIngredToList(7, "Pppp", 10, "b");
addIngredToList(12, "Kkkk", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(2, "Ffff", 8, "a");
addIngredToList(4, "Ssss", 10, "b");
addIngredToList(15, "Vvvv", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(5, "Iiii", 10, "b");
addIngredToList(21, "Llll", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(22, "Mmmm", 9, "a");
addIngredToList(7, "Bbbb", 12, "b");
addIngredToList(8, "Eeee", 8, "b");
addIngredToList(9, "Gggg", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(10, "Cccc", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(11, "Aaaa", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(6, "Nnnn", 10, "b");
addIngredToList(3, "Zzzz", 8, "a");
addIngredToList(13, "Mmmm", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(14, "Rrrr", 6, "c");
addIngredToList(17, "Hhhh", 5, "d");
addIngredToList(18, "Uuuu", 5, "d");
addIngredToList(19, "Qqqq", 5, "d");
addIngredToList(20, "Xxxx", 5, "d");

//Create Rows Empty Rows and TDs with appropiate classes in each column
for (i = 0, z = ingredients.length; i < z; i++) {
  var emptyRow = "<tr class='emptyRow'></tr>";
  $('table#tblGrid').append(emptyRow);
  emptyRowSelector = $('tr.emptyRow');
  for (c = 0, b = ingredients[i].length; c < b; c++) {
    var columnID = " " + $('table#tblGrid').find('th').eq(c).text().toLowerCase().toString();
    var emptyTD = "<td colspan='2' class='emptyTD" + columnID + "'></td>";
    emptyRowSelector.eq(i).append(emptyTD);
  }
}

//Create a TD  with ingredient array attributes.
var $rowScanner = $('table#tblGrid').find('tr').not($('tr:eq(0)'));
var $headerScanner = $('table#tblGrid').find('tr:eq(0) th');

for (g = 0, e = $rowScanner.length; g < e; g++) {
  var idCol = ingredients[g][0];
  var nameCol = ingredients[g][1];
  var priceCol = ingredients[g][2];
  var categCol = ingredients[g][3];

  var tdCell = "<td colspan='2' data-id='" + idCol + "' data-catg='" + categCol + "' class='" + categCol.toLowerCase().toString() + "'>" + nameCol + "<span class='pull-right'>kr." + priceCol + "</span></td>";
  var classChecker = "td." + ingredients[g][3].toString() + "";
  $rowScanner.eq(g).find(classChecker).replaceWith(tdCell).addClass("targetFound");
}

$headerScanner.each(function(i, v) {
  var assignClass = $(this).text();
  $(this).addClass(assignClass).attr("colspan", "2");
});

//Create a temporary table to hold and sort cells.
$("<table style='display:none;' class='temp'><tr><td class='placeHolder'>Place Holder</td></tr></table>").prependTo($('body'));

$rowScanner.find('td').not('td:empty').each(function() {
  var $cloneIt = $(this).clone();
  $cloneIt.appendTo($('table.temp tr'));
  var whitelist = ["class", "colspan"];
  var attributes = this.attributes;
  var i = attributes.length;
  while (i--) {
    var attr = attributes[i];
    if ($.inArray(attr.name, whitelist) == -1)
      this.removeAttributeNode(attr);
  }
  $(this).html("");
});

$('td.placeHolder').remove();
$('#tblGrid').find('td').removeClass("emptyTD");

//This section was solved by Jean-Claude of StackOverflow
//Sort TDs back into correct columns from the temporary table
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120353/transpose-array-of-tds-into-columns-jquery/37121225#37121225
$(function() {
  var $tempScanner = $('table.temp tr td');
  var tempArry = [];

  $tempScanner.each(function(i, el) {
    var d = {};
    d.text = $(el).text();
    d.html = $(el).html();
    d.class = $(el).attr('class');
    tempArry.push(d);
  });

  function compareObj(o1, o2) {
    return o1.text > o2.text;
  }

  tempArry = tempArry.sort(compareObj);
  console.log(tempArry);

  for (var i = 0; i < tempArry.length; i++) {
    var tdClass = tempArry[i].class;
    $('#tblGrid td.' + tdClass + ':empty:first').html(tempArry[i].html).addClass('sorted');
  }
});

//Remove Empty Rows
var removeEmpty = setInterval(function() {
  var emptyTD = $('td.sorted');
  if (emptyTD.length > 0) {
    $rowScanner.each(function() {
      if ($(this).find(emptyTD).length > 0) {

      } else {
        $(this).remove();
        $('table.temp').remove();
      }
    });
    console.log(emptyTD.length);
    clearInterval(removeEmpty);
  } else {
    var doNothing = "";
  }
}, 50);
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  padding: 6px;
}
th {
  font-weight: 700;
}
span.pull-right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.a,
.A {
  background-color: #ACE;
}
.b,
.B {
  background-color: #FAF;
}
.c,
.C {
  background-color: #BAB;
}
.d,
.D {
  background-color: #ECA;
}
.targetFound {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblGrid">
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```