# jQuery Inject TD into appropriate Column (Tetris Style)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have two tables. One is a temporary table and one is a master table that will ultimately be sorted with the contents of the temporary table.

The main reason for this question is that I have too many empty cells in the master table.

I seek to extract the cells from the temp table and put them in the appropriate column in the master table, ascending so that the end result will be 4 columns that only have empty cells where necessary, to allow for normal table flow, without breaking the table flow.

Every element has an associated class, but I just can seem to create a selector that will safely iterate over the temporary table and the master table without breaking the master table.  The only hint I can give is that I may need to build a for loop that utilizes the `replaceWith()` and `break` jQuery and JavaScript methods, respectively.

Any table rows, after that has been accomplished, that have only empty tds, can be removed.

Lastly, this question stems from another [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058963/dynamic-table-insert-items-in-cells-sorted-corresponding-to-thead?noredirect=1#comment61740164_37058963) question that I nearly have solved, where, this is the last hurdle that I need to cross to solve it.

Work in progress of that question can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ae0oygtu/12/).

```js
var $tempScanner = $('table.temp tr td');

$tempScanner.each(function(i, v) {
  var $tempClass = $(v).attr("class");
  var $tempTD = $(v);

  $('#tblGrid tr').each(function(x, o) {
    var tdMatch = $(this).eq(x).find($('td.' + $tempClass));
    if (tdMatch.length > 0) {
      $(this).eq(x).find($('td.' + $tempClass)).replaceWith($tempTD);
    }
    console.log(tdMatch);
  });
});
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #111;
  padding: 6px;
}
th {
  font-weight: 700;
}
span.pull-right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.a,
.A {
  background-color: #ACE;
}
.b,
.B {
  background-color: #FAF;
}
.c,
.C {
  background-color: #BAB;
}
.d,
.D {
  background-color: #ECA;
}
.targetFound {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="display:;" class="temp">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="1" data-catg="a" class="a">Ooo<span class="pull-right">kr.8</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="7" data-catg="b" class="b">Pppp<span class="pull-right">kr.10</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="12" data-catg="c" class="c">Kkkk<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="2" data-catg="a" class="a">Ffff<span class="pull-right">kr.8</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="4" data-catg="b" class="b">Ssss<span class="pull-right">kr.10</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="15" data-catg="c" class="c">Vvvv<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="5" data-catg="b" class="b">Iiii<span class="pull-right">kr.10</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="21" data-catg="c" class="c">Llll<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="22" data-catg="a" class="a">Mmmm<span class="pull-right">kr.9</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="7" data-catg="b" class="b">Bbbb<span class="pull-right">kr.12</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="8" data-catg="b" class="b">Eeee<span class="pull-right">kr.8</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="9" data-catg="c" class="c">Gggg<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="10" data-catg="c" class="c">Cccc<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="11" data-catg="c" class="c">Aaaa<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="6" data-catg="b" class="b">Nnnn<span class="pull-right">kr.10</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="3" data-catg="a" class="a">Zzzz<span class="pull-right">kr.8</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="13" data-catg="c" class="c">Mmmm<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="14" data-catg="c" class="c">Rrrr<span class="pull-right">kr.6</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="17" data-catg="d" class="d">Hhhh<span class="pull-right">kr.5</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="18" data-catg="d" class="d">Uuuu<span class="pull-right">kr.5</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="19" data-catg="d" class="d">Qqqq<span class="pull-right">kr.5</span>
      </td>
      <td colspan="2" data-id="20" data-catg="d" class="d">Xxxx<span class="pull-right">kr.5</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="tblGrid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="A" colspan="2">A</th>
      <th class="B" colspan="2">B</th>
      <th class="C" colspan="2">C</th>
      <th class="D" colspan="2">D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="emptyRow">
      <td colspan="2" class="a"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="b"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="d"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: why are you helping someone else when you don't know what you're doing? Create a 2nd html table? How about an array of objects containing the data, then iterate through them.

Comment: @yezzz, the temp table _is_ the second table converted from the master table, only to be simply restructured into an easier to read order.  I believe your suggestion of arrays will work.  I know can `.push()` objects into an array.  I do not know how to access, for example, the class of the objects in the array.

Comment: what I mean is: it would have been better advice to use an array of objects instead of all those addIngredToList(1, "Ooo", 8, "a"); lines, or you could have created it inside that function. Array items can be targeted via index, and object via keys.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of various ways to do this.

You could build the table first. Get the number of items for each category. The highest number is the number of TR's that need to be created. An array with the data would be handy here.

For each column (category) keep a variable of the last vertical position that was filled, or the first empty slot. That way you know which one to fill.

You can target the TR and TD you need with eg. a css selector (nth-of-type) or an index. In javascript you can also use cellIndex and rowIndex.

If you want to create TR's dynamically, then every time you want to fill a TD you first check if there's already a TR to put the TD into, otherwise create it.

Get rid of the temp table. It only complicates things.

Also, if all cells in a table have `colspan="2"` then you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question a different way and received the correct answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120353/transpose-array-of-tds-into-columns-jquery/37121225#37121225) post.

```
$(function() {
  var $tempScanner = $('table.temp tr td');
  var tempArry = [];

  $tempScanner.each(function(i, el) {
    var d = {};
    d.text = $(el).text();
    d.html = $(el).html();
    d.class = $(el).attr('class');
    tempArry.push(d);
  });

  function compareObj(o1, o2) {
    return o1.text > o2.text;
  }

  tempArry = tempArry.sort(compareObj);
  console.log(tempArry);

  for (var i = 0; i < tempArry.length; i++) {
    var tdClass = tempArry[i].class;
    $('#tblGrid td.' + tdClass + ':empty:first').html(tempArry[i].html);
  }

});
```

Comment: well congrats, tempArry is what you could have created via addIngredToList() instead of extra step of a temp table etc.